# Latent variable modelling use

Tags: regression, latent-variable

I am currently working on a project and I found that latent variable models could be a potential approach to my problem. I have read some introductory theory about it. However, from that I could not be convinced that it is also applicable to my problem.

The setting is as follows: I would like to predict values $Y_i$, which we can think of as a quantative indicator. Hence, $Y_i$ is continuous. I have reason to believe that $Y_i$ is correlated to some continuous predictor variables $X_{i,1},X_{i,2}$, since $Y_i=X_{i,1}+X_{i,2}$ show similarities in trend, but are not perfect vertical translations. Also, the similarities in trend somewhat differ for each $i$. Indeed, there seems to be some gap that $X_{i,1}$ and $X_{i,2}$ cannot capture. Could this be captured somehow by combining $Y_i, X_{i,1}$, and $X_{i,2}$ in a latent variable model?

If not, is there perhaps another method I ought to read about?

Comment: Why are you considering latent variable models? What's wrong with multiple regression?

Comment: @PeterFlom good point. I actually tried that at the start and I believe I didn't properly looked at graphs of the predictions against the actual observations. Just now I tried multiple (linear) regression and the graphs looked very promosing, but I remember I kind of disregarded it since the $p$-values were very high. This again happens for the graphs which gave promising results. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The p values might be high because the sample is small or because your theory is incorrect or because you are missing variables or for other reasons.